# What is the "elegant" method of using BackOffPolicy

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I've noticed occasionally that my Drive SDK calls fail periodically with a 500 error, retrying the request usually fixes the error immediately.  Looking at the Google documentation, its recommended to use the exponential back off technique, I wrote my own implementation which works fine, however while debugging I happened to bump into the interface BackOffPolicy, with more investigation I even found the implementation ExponentialBackOffPolicy.

So instead of managing this myself, I thought best to remove my implementation and let the SDK do it for me.  The backoff policy can (from my knowledge) be set with a built HTTP request, so its quite easy to use when manually building requests or when using batch requests, however I cannot seem to find the easiest place to inject this when using the core SDK, for example, if I want to set a backoff policy for:

```
drive.files().get(id).execute();
```

I cannot do something like:

```
drive.files().get(id)
     .setBackOffPolicy(new ExponentialBackOffPolicy())
     .execute();
```

I would need to do this:

```
drive.files().get(id)
     .buildHttpRequest()
     .setBackOffPolicy(new ExponentialBackOffPolicy())
     .execute();
```

However if I do that, then I would also need to reproduce the parsing logic of the execute method of Drive.Files.Get and convert the result to a File object which is obviously not an ideal approach.  Is there an easier way to "generically" add this to the request or perhaps a way to set a default back off policy for all requests?

If not, perhaps this could be introduced into a future version of the Drive SDK?

Thanks,
David

Comment: did you ever find out more about the SDK `ExponentialBackOffPolicy()`? Like you, I've seen references to it but never anything concrete, and it certainly would be nice to reuse something in the client SDK rather than maintain it on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Google made Exponential Backoff is only used when downloading or uploading content in the drive Java API. You need your own implementation for the other requests.

What I did to implement it for any request is wrap a Callable executing once the request and letting the wrapper class do the exception handling and repeating of the request.

Comment: This is similar to my approach, I have an "ExecutionManager" that manages the retry algorithm, I actually am using Googles ExponentialBackOff policy class in the background.

Comment: as of Feb 2015, you must implement `exponential back-off` for uploads or downloads as Google Drive API is full of exceptions/inconsistency -- and you will regret it if you don't

Answer (score 2):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes an example showing how to correctly implement exponential backoff with the Drive API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors

Comment: Thanks @claudio, that is what I was referring to and I did follow this and made my own implementation (which works). However I "accidentally" bumped into an already baked in Google solution within the HttpRequest which has the ability to internally set the BackOffPolicy it seems this would be the most ideal approach to manage exponential backoff no?

Comment: I wrote a wrapper for using the ExponentialBackOff class at:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/configure#retry

Please try it and let me know how it works .

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo that looks really interesting... I would like it if there were more concrete examples of using it to handle 5xx and 4xx API errors from the Java Drive SDK. Now that I look at it more it seems like it may be for a different person than mine (which is loading hundreds of files back-to-back into Drive -- not sure if that fits a publish/subscribe form)

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. @mmcrae You can use HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler.BackOffRequired.ALWAYS to retry everytime (5xx as well as 4xx). Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code to use for exponential backoff:

```
boolean thisIsARetry = false;
boolean keepRetrying = true;
int delayTime = 2;
int maxDelayTime = 4;

while(keepRetrying && delayTime <= maxDelayTime) {
    if(thisIsARetry) {
        //sleep for delayTime seconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * delayTime);
            delayTime *= 2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //print exception
            delayTime *= 2;
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        thisIsARetry = true;
    }

    //the actual network request or some other operation here
    if(ACTUAL_OPERATION_SUCCESS) {
        keepRetrying = false;
    }
}
```